# 2001 Hyundai Sonata won't start dash lights work key reminder dings but wont crank at all

Tags: starting, hyundai, sonata

My 2001 Hyundai Sonata was starting fine went to kids volleyball game was there for 45 minutes went to leave put key in ignition My dash lights came on and the key reminder dinged....tried to turn the key to actually start the car and NOTHING.....no sound what so ever no clicking no cranking again dash lights worked key dinged but nothing when turning the key all the way. Someone tried to jump me but when he put the jumper cables on my battery he got no spark of any kind and the car still wouldn't make a sound or crank so I was told it's not the battery cause even if the battery was bad if someone tried to jump it the car would start! I don't know what the hell is wrong but I need to get it out of the school's parking lot before it's towed....someone PLEASE HELP I'm a single mom of 4 kids and I desperately-- need my vehicle!